# Aligning td's in a table

Tags: javascript, html, css

In the below table how can Item6 be aligned with Item2 when the table is constructed dynamically? Is there a pure css or css3 way of achieving this?

Current Table

[image]

Required Table

[image]

```
<table class="qe">
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>Item1</td>
        <td>Item2</td>
        <td>Item3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Item4</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Item5asfasfasf</td>
        <td>Item6</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/jxvf9arL/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `colspan` attribute properly and remove `display:table;` rule for `table tr`, it's messing with table layout:

```css
table{
    width:500px;
    border:1px solid #000;
    table-layout:fixed;
}
table td{
    width:33%;
    border:1px solid #777;
    background:#eaeaea;
}
```

```html
<table class="qe">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Item1</td>
            <td>Item2</td>
            <td>Item3</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="3">Item4</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Item5asfasfasf</td>
            <td colspan="2">Item6</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

you should add colspan to the tds. 
so if the maximum columns is N, and the current row has m columns, you should add colspan=n-m to the last cell in the row.

also, something in the tr stylying

```
table tr{
    display:table;
    width:100%;   
    }
```

is wrong. 
    http://jsfiddle.net/jxvf9arL/7/ 
would work